# How do I get form fields with a certain name (attribute)?

Tags: jquery, html

What I am doing right now is using the HTML5 data attributes to hold some static information that I'd like to postback as well. Also, I am using Steve's (forgot last name) Index HtmlHelper and ASP.NET MVC 3. What I would like to do is use some javascript/jquery to only get the INPUT and SELECT tags that have "`.SomeProperty`" in the name attribute. I think this is part of what I need:

```
var formData = $('#' + div_id).find('input, select');
```

But I'm not sure how to filter on the property.

An example of what my tags look like:

```
<form action="/TestEdit/Sections/5/100100/44/A" id="line_756_A4" method="post">        
    <div style="clear:both; padding:1%;">       
        <div class="section">
            A
        </div>
        <div class="number">
            4
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
            Fourth Row of in the sun
        </div>
        <div class="ctrl">  

            <input type="hidden" name="RowInput.index" autocomplete="off" value="ec65a509-12c7-4029-b774-10b84ae73a66" />
            <input type="hidden" name="RowInput.index" autocomplete="off" value="41936720-0509-428c-8aaf-3bd547cc8084" />

            <label for="RowInput_41936720-0509-428c-8aaf-3bd547cc8084__InputtedData">Space Station</label>
            <input data-ctrltypeid="4" data-instid="4" id="RowInput_41936720-0509-428c-8aaf-3bd547cc8084__InputtedData" name="RowInput[41936720-0509-428c-8aaf-3bd547cc8084].InputtedData" type="radio" value="1" />

            <label for="RowInput_41936720-0509-428c-8aaf-3bd547cc8084__InputtedData">Solar System</label>
            <input data-ctrltypeid="4" data-instid="4" id="RowInput_41936720-0509-428c-8aaf-3bd547cc8084__InputtedData" name="RowInput[41936720-0509-428c-8aaf-3bd547cc8084].InputtedData" type="radio" value="2" />

            <label for="RowInput_41936720-0509-428c-8aaf-3bd547cc8084__InputtedData">Galaxy</label>
            <input checked="checked" data-ctrltypeid="4" data-instid="4" id="RowInput_41936720-0509-428c-8aaf-3bd547cc8084__InputtedData" name="RowInput[41936720-0509-428c-8aaf-3bd547cc8084].InputtedData" type="radio" value="3" />

            <br /> 

        </div>
        <div class="done">
            <input id="10" type="button" onclick="javascript:postBackPart($(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id'));" value="button" />
        </div>
        <div class="foo">
            107
        </div>
        <div class="bar">
            18129
        </div>
        <div class="baz">
            512
        </div>
        <div class="baz">
            8052
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is `.SomeProperty` *part* of the name, or the name in its entirety?

Comment: @dotnetN00b, please don't tag your question with asp.net-mvc. It has nothing to do with it. This is pure javascript/jquery question.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov since I am asking this in reference to HTML produced by MVC 3, I think it is.

Comment: @dotnetN00b, no this doesn't really matter. You have HTML markup. The server side language that was used to produce this markup is of no importance at all to the question. You are asking how to manipulate this markup on the client side (using jquery in your case), and on the client side, it doesn't really matter how this markup was generated.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I understand what you're saying but I still think a MVC tag is still not inappropriate. But for now, we'll move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input, select').filter('[name*=".SomeProperty"]')
```

That will get `input` and `select` elements that have ".SomeProperty" in their name. Note it does not require that the name is *exactly* ".SomeProperty"; rather, that it contains it.

From the comment underneath your question, this seems to be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
// get all elements that have that attribute with the given value
$('*[attributeName=attributeValue]');
```